# upsampling imbalanced dataset in decision tree

Tags: dataset, statistics, decision-trees

I have a imbalanced dataset with 3 output labels with one class with 98 percent and other two classes with 1 percent each. I need to run decision tree on this dataset. Should i be upsampling this dataset by duplicating rows? 
Would this effect the impurity, entropy or information gain for nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't simply duplicate data.

You should do -

1. Oversampling using standard techniques e.g. SMOTe
2. Undersampling
3. Class weights
4. Must try - **Combining** few of these

Check these links -

[MachineLearningMastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/) and [jeremyjordan](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/imbalanced-data/)